Explanation of the notation for probability measures in the context of the Kullback-Leibler divergence sought
I came across some notation in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence on the Kullback-Leibler divergence that I am unfamiliar with, in which the probability measures are written as if they were a function of the infinitesimal $dx$ (and where $dx$ does not appear on its own under the integral sign).
The following quote illustrates this notation:

More generally, if $P$ and $Q$ are probability measures on a measurable space $\mathcal{X}$, and $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$, then the relative entropy from $Q$ to $P$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
D_{KL}(P\parallel Q) = \int_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \log \left(\frac{P(dx)}{Q(dx)}\right) P(dx)
\end{equation}
where $P(dx)/Q(dx)$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of $P$ with respect to $Q$.

Could anyone please explain exactly what this notation is implying? Is it just saying that $P$ and $Q$ are continuous distributions and that one should integrate over all values of $P$?
Why would one not just write this as
\begin{equation}
D_{KL}(P\parallel Q) = \int_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \log \left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right) P(x)dx?
\end{equation}

No, $P$ and $Q$ are not necessarily continuous. Here $P$ and $Q$ are arbitrary, so they can be wacky, like part continuous, part discrete. If $P$ is absolutely continuous, then $P(dx) = p(x),dx$, but obviously not all measures are of this form. $P(dx)$ is the general notation.

Its just notation. Some people write $\int f(x) \mathrm{d}P(x)$, and some write $\int f(x) P(\mathrm{d}x),$ both mean integrating a function, $f,$ with respect to a measure, $P$.
